# Video not showing up in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

a video tag exists inside bootstrap modal as modal content . i can hear the audio of the video tag but it is not visible . When i attach the video tag to some other element eg body , it properly shows up there .

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="video_call_modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Sign up view" data-backdrop="" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog ">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <video autoplay id="chat_video"></video>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Inside javascript

```
     $("#chat_video").attr("src",window.URL.createObjectURL(Stream))
     $("#video_call_modal").modal({keyboard:false})
      $("#video_call_modal").modal('show')
```

Comment: Set some very large z-index to the video tag to position it over the modal window.

Comment: not helping .  i tried .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use Bootstrap's [**modal shown callback**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) to load the video. I'm guessing that it's sizing to the modal before it has dimensions.

```
$('#video_call_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#chat_video").attr("src",window.URL.createObjectURL(Stream));
});
```

And for the love of Pete, put semicolons on those statements! :-)